# How to get all Objects of an array with value condition

Tags: php, laravel

I'm absolutely new to php/laravel world so sorry if my question is simple.

Language: php with laravel.

What : I want to get all objects who contain the name of the users.

```
//Exemple of my users Array
  ($users = ["name1", "name2","name4"])
//Forms is an array who contain multiple object, each object have a reference to a user Name. 
  $Forms = [{_id: 1, title : "title1", userName : "name1" },  {_id: 2, title : "title2", userName : "name2" }, {_id: 3, title : "title3", userName : "name3" }, {_id: 4, title : "title4", userName : "name4" },{_id: 5, title : "title5", userName : "name1" }]

//here i want to get form with name1, name2 and name4 
   foreach ($users  as $user) { 
           $allForm = Forms::where('userName ', $user)->get();  
};
```

Problematic: I only received 2 objects (objects from the first user of my array).

Exemple: here i want to get every forms who contain  "name1", "name2","name4" but i will received only every forms with "name1".

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: try `collect($Forms)->where('userName', 'name1')->all()` https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-where

Comment: Not getting an error, just getting the form of the first user and not all . I will try thank you :)

Comment: Why is line 1 in parenthesis?

Answer (score 0):

This should work as per your requirements:

```
$users = ["name1", "name2","name4"];
    $Forms = [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'title' => 'title1',
            'userName' => 'name1'
        ]
    ];
    $collection = collect($Forms);

    $results = $collection->whereIn('userName', $users)->toArray();

    dd($results);
```

use `toArray()` function to convert the collection

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$users = ["name1", "name2","name4"];

$forms = Form::whereIn('userName', $users)->get();
```

Comment: This is exactly what i have tried like 5 minutes ago. in a forEach and without. without a foreach "users" i'm getting an empty array. In a forEach i only received the forms from "user1"

Comment: did you try yo use `dd($forms)` to check if there's a result ?

Comment: in the "for each" i'm getting "Argument #1 ($bindings) must be of type array, string given, called in" and without the"foreach" " #items: []
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false"

Comment: does your form table have the value given by the array of $users ?

Comment: I'm not sure i have understand your question but in my "users" array i have a list of name and in my "forms" array i have multiple object. each object have a value "UserName".